# URL Syntax: Hiding page numbers and session id

Tags: url-rewriting, oracle-apex

How to hide Pagenumber, Session ID of Oracle APEX URL

eg: http://apex.somewhere.com/pls/apex/f?p=4350:1:220883407765693447

I want to hide `f?p=4350:1:220883407765693447` from end user. Is it possible to hide these from URL Syntax?

I am using Oracle APEX 4.2 version

Comment: http://krisrice.blogspot.com.ar/2007/02/better-apex-urls.html

Comment: What's the driving purpose for this request? There are many examples & presentations of "prettifying urls" available.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i can't add comment. In apex 5 if i create branch to page and assign it to button. The result is:
http://apex.somewhere.com:8088/apex/wwv_flow.accept
Here is picture of my branch settings:
[image]

You can set "Page Access Protecion" to No URL Access.
I hope this can help you.